# How to add taxonomy in menus?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

- Book (Custom Post Type)

  - Fiction (Tax)
  - Science (Tax)
  - History (Tax)

----------OR-----------

- Book

  - Genre (Tax)

    - Fiction (Term)
    - Science (Term)
    - History (Term)

Which of these is "good way" of doing it?

With the former one( which is what i have currently in my admin menu, i've 'register_taxonomy' functions for each of them ) i can't choose the 'Tax' to show in menus.

Whereas with the later one i can add them to menus and need only one 'register_taxonomy' function.

Comment: It's completely unclear (at least for me) what is being asked here.

Comment: i can't add the taxonomies to menu (which'll take to the page listing all of it's terms), should i add them (taxonomies) as custom links? sorry for being unclear

Comment: Maybe you want to add screenshots or tell to what exactly you're referring - best show your _full_ code samples. It's still completely unclear.

Comment: sorry i can't upload screen shots (bc of rep). You can add only terms(child categories) of a taxonomy and not taxonomy itself to the menu, right?

Comment: You can - but one of the higher rep users (for e.g.: me) will need to approve it. If it doesn't work for you, just add the link to your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question ... the 'good' way is the way which ...

you are most

1. comfortable with developing,
2. is easy to maintain going forward, and
3. solves the problem.

Personally - I prefer flatter taxonomy structures so option 1 ...

For Option 2 ....  you didn't say if in the future you would have more 2nd level taxonomies. Currently you only have 'genres'  in the future would you add 'year of issue' or 'format'.

Either way ... always refer to points 1 and 2.